# Modify Golang internal file?

Tags: go, version-control

I had the idea of adding a `sync.WaitGroup` `Limit(max int)` function to resrict the number of the `WaitGroup` counter.

So I opened the `waitgroup.go` file in `go/src/sync` and made the changes, saved the file and tried testing it in a main.go file on my desktop. When I ran the file, it says:

```
$ go run main.go
wg.Limit undefined (type sync.WaitGroup has no field or method Limit)
```

To fix this error message, I copied the folder from `go/src/sync` into the folder on my desktop containing my `main.go` file and changed the import from `sync` to `./sync`.

After running `go run main.go` this time, I got the following output:

```
$ go run main.go
sync\mutex.go:14:2: use of internal package not allowed
sync\pool.go:8:2: use of internal package not allowed
sync\rwmutex.go:8:2: use of internal package not allowed
sync\waitgroup.go:8:2: use of internal package not allowed
```

To fix these messages, I copied `go/src/internal` into the folder on my desktop containing my `main.go` file and I modified all the files in `./sync` that reference `internal/..` to `./internal/..`

I run it again and I get the following output:

```
$ go run main.go
# _/C_/.../sync
sync\mutex.go:20: missing function body for "throw"
sync\pool.go:66: missing function body for "fastrand"
sync\pool.go:249: missing function body for "runtime_registerPoolCleanup"
sync\pool.go:250: missing function body for "runtime_procPin"
sync\pool.go:251: missing function body for "runtime_procUnpin"
sync\runtime.go:14: missing function body for "runtime_Semacquire"
sync\runtime.go:17: missing function body for "runtime_SemacquireMutex"
sync\runtime.go:23: missing function body for "runtime_Semrelease"
sync\runtime.go:36: missing function body for "runtime_notifyListAdd"
sync\runtime.go:39: missing function body for "runtime_notifyListWait"
sync\runtime.go:39: too many errors
```

---

**How can I implement my simple idea by modifying the source files of `go/src` without receiving these errors?**

Comment: Just recompile the sync package in place.

Comment: @JimB How do I recompile it?

Comment: Just like any other, `go install sync`. Since many things depend on that package `go install std` might be more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your installation of Go, navigate to the `src` folder and run the file called `run.bat` which will recompile all the packages removing the first error you described.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't do this by changing the standard library, but instead wrap the WaitGroup to keep track of the counter like so:

```
type wg_limit struct {
    wg           sync.WaitGroup
    current, max int
}

func (wgl *wg_limit) Add(delta int) error {
    if wgl.current+delta > wgl.max {
    return fmt.Errorf("counter exceeded (current: %d, max: %d)", wgl.current, wgl.max)
    }
    wgl.current += delta
    wgl.wg.Add(delta)
    return nil
}

func (wgl *wg_limit) Done() {
    wgl.current -= 1
    wgl.wg.Done()
}
```

Then init wg_limit with a value for max and use the resulting variable just like a WaitGroup:

```
wgl := wg_limit{max: 3}
if err := wgl.Add(1); err != nil {
    // go something()
    // ...
    wgl.Done()
}
```

If the WaitGroup counter would be exceeded by the delta of Add(delta), an error is returned and the WaitGroup is unchanged.

Comment: But I was thinking of making a pull request to the Golang github repository.
But thank you for this code, I'll probably be using it.

Comment: You will need a mutex to manage concurrent access, while checking and modifying `wgl.current`